# Python's module for testing mongoDB performance.

Tags: python, mongodb

I try to find python's module for performance testing of mongoDB.
I want to load about 100.000 documents to database. And performing some standard operations under it, like create, drop, update and etc.
So, I need module (like a framework for bot develop) or program what can run these tests for me.
In my mind it will be like a simple bot with multithreading support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used the [timeit](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html) module for performance testing to great effect in the past.

You could also checkout: [mongo-perf](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-perf) - [blog article here](http://blog.beyondfog.com/mongodb-how-to-benchmark-and-test-performance-using-mongo-perf)

Comment: Denis: Added a link to mongo-perf as well for you to check out